# Beginner Bluetooth Stack Advice

Tags: security, bluetooth, stack

Hay peeps

I'm relatively new to Bluetooth and its inner workings and am trying to still understand some of the concepts and procedures. My question relates to the Bluetooth stack.

I understand there is a Bluetooth stack on the OS side such as Linux Bluez, Windows, Androids Bluedroid etc... but do peripheral devices implement a stack within themselves for example I connect a Bluetooth mouse to a Linux system, Linux of course implements the Bluez stack does the mouse them implement a Bluetooth stack?

I am trying to understand which device will implement security in this situation would it be the Linux with its Bluez or the mouse peripheral.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, But the difference is that peripheral devices wont support all the profiles and features compared to a Bluetooth stack in OS like Linux or android.

Bluetooth is one of the wireless protocols. Protocol is a procedure or system of rules to follow. So both devices should follow the same protocol for communication. If one of these devices is not following the required protocol, then the other device can't communicate with it. It is like a common language between two people. To follow these protocols all device should have stack. Bluetooth mouse and keyboard also will have Bluetooth stack.

Bluetooth is divided into core protocols and [profiles](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview). Core and some profiles are needed for all devices for scanning, pairing etc Example GAP, GATT. Some profile are for a particular use case. For Keyboard and Mouse is is HID profile. For steaming HiFi audio it is A2DP. For voice communication it is HFP. Each peripheral device will implement only the required profiles for their use case because of memory and cost constraints.

The OS will generally implement all the profiles because it needed to connect to most of the peripheral devices. For example A2DP to connect with Bluetooth headset, HID/HOGP to connect with mouse, SPP/OBEX for file transfer over Bluetooth.

Security is implemented in GAP in BREDR and SMP in BLE. These are implemented in all the devices.

Bluetooth stacks are implemented in different ways too. Some places it is entirely implemented in Bluetooth controller(Mostly along with application all in single chip), But in some place it is split between host CPU(In OS) and Bluetooth controller(In firmware). Bludroid and Bluez are the upper part running in the Host CPU(Above HCI). There will be a lower part of the stacks(Above [HCI](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/simplelink_cc2640r2_sdk_1_40_00_45/docs/blestack/ble_user_guide/html/ble-stack-3.x/hci.html)) running in the Bluetooth controller attached to the Device.

The best place to start learning about Bluetooth is [Bluetooth SIG website](https://www.bluetooth.com/)